# Cannot create custom translated path alias for /user/login

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I cannot create a path alias for spanish translation.

When I try to create, it says `Route is invalid or you don't have access`

Saw this but it doesn't have an answer: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/236915

How can I translate the `/user/login path?`

[image]

Comment: You can try using `user` path only without `login`. After saving you can try to edit the alias. For me, it didn't work at first when I added `user/login` then it worked for both paths after being saved for the first time. Not sure why though

Comment: What Drupal and PHP versions are you using? I tried on simplytest.me, and I was able to set a path alias for /user/login, when using English as interface language.

Comment: When I set the language to Spanish and the detect method to path, the path added for Spanish is es, not es-es. Also in this case, I am able to set a path alias for /user/login.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths
Should do the job... Good luck!

Comment: The user wants to provide a path alias that is used when the language used the site is Spanish. The suggested module doesn't change a route path basing on the language.